# ¿Cómo controlar los errores de mongoose para no mostrar información importante en producción?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy tratando de manejar los errores en diferentes casos con mongoose, y uno de ellos es por ejemplo, si la conexión no se establece por las credenciales (user, pass).

Lo normal es que si las credenciales son incorrectas, mande el siguiente mensaje:

```
(node:9272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: Authentication failed.
```

Pero lo que yo quiero es mostrar el error con un simple mensaje, por ejemplo: 'Error DB', sin mas.

Este es mi código donde trato de controlar ese evento:

```
function connect (callback){
  let uri = `mongodb://${wrong_user}:${wrong_pass}@${host}:${port}/${db}`
  mongoose.connect(uri, err => {
    callback(err, `Connected in ${config.host}/${config.port}`)
  })
}
```

Y lo uso así:

```
connect ((err, uri) => {
  if (err)
    return new Error('Error DB')
  else
    console.log(uri)
})
```

Y sin embargo me sigue mostrando que el error es la autenticación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los errores que deberías mostrar, en un primer lugar, deben ser de validación. Los errores internos no deben ser expuestos al cliente porque a éste no le interesan los detalles, además, usuarios mal intencionados pueden aprovechar ésta información para abrir brechas de seguridad.

Los errores de validación soy muy importantes en un sistema, ya que así mostramos al usuario las reglas que debe seguir al intentar persistir datos. Mongoose tiene una jerarquía de errors, desde `MongoseError` hasta `ValidationError`. Cada hijo dentro de la jerarquía hereda la propiedad `errors`, el cual es un array de mensajes de error.

**Manejando errores a nivel de base de datos**

Un problema que tienes es que estás devolviendo un error dentro de un callback, lo cual no logrará el efecto deseado. En su lugar, debes manejar el error dentro del callback y mostrar una respuesta la usuario o algo.

```
mongoose
  .connect(...)
  .then(() => {
    connected = true;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    connected = false;
  });
```

Si usas Express o Koa puedes hacer un middleware para que verifique la conexión a la base de datos y responder de acuerdo a ella:

```
app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
  if (!connected) {
    return res.status(500).send("Couldn't stablish connection. Please, contact the admin");
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});
```

De ésta manera, si hacemos una petición a cualquier URL del sistema y ha ocurrido un error de autenticación con la base de datos, obtendremos dicho mensaje seguido de un error 500 (interval server error).

**Manejando errores de validación de modelos**

A nivel de validación de esquemas/modelos, lo único que debemos hacer es enviar los mensajes de errors que Mongoose ha elaborado por nosotros de acuerdo a las restricciones en los esquemas. Por ejemplo tenemos el siguiente esquema:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  }
  ...
});
```

Si insertamos un `username` duplicado, obtendremos un `ValidationError` el cual podemos manejar:

```
User
  .save({ ... })
  .then((user) => {
    res.jsonp(user);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.jsonp({
      success: false,
      errors: err.errors
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas que la aplicación detenga la ejecución en lugar de usar un return en la función es necesario un throw:

```
throw new Error('Error DB');
```

Otro problema es que 'Error DB' no es nada descriptivo y en una aplicación en produccion es necesario solucionar los problemas rapido.

Por eso te recomiendo usar un logger como el de winston o el que prefieras y loggear por ejemplo a un archivo. Siempre dejando errores descriptivos no un simple 'paso por aca' o 'error db'. 'DB Connection error' por ejemplo.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta :) De hecho mi idea es que en producción no muestre información detallada sobre los errores puesto que puede ser información usada en contra del sistema, pero me has dado la idea de mostrar el mensaje general del error y a la vez guardar el detalle en un archivo log (en producción, en desarrollo obvio sí mostrar toda la info)